# Making launch screens with single color background

Tags: ios, app

In iOS App there is something called a “launch screen” (the screen that appear before the app actually launches and is not equivalent to the splash screen), which can be provided by two ways, either as a storyboard or a set of images.

Since I layout a large portion of my controls programmatically, there is no efficient way to reproduce them on the launchscreen storyboard, and because I do need to provide one, I’m left with two ways:

1. set the storyboard with the background colour of my app (and that’s all: no other UIControls are included).
2. make screen captures of the app and provide them as a set.

The first one is indeed easier to maintain, but I want to ask:

1. whether this will be rejected during the app review (e.g. contradicting guidelines), and
2. whether this is a bad practice (this doesn’t only focus on iOS App but also other systems which use launch screens to enhance user impressions).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Apple - Human Interface Guidelines -
Launch Screen](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/)

Comment: I did read it, but I can’t simply conclude that a single color background is unacceptable.

Comment: Read it again. It never said single color was unacceptable.